# Cucumber Step Definitions - Must use Given, And, Then ... etc?

Tags: cucumber, calabash

Do I have to use Given, And, Then, etc... when I am doing a step definition?

For example in my feature file I have `Then I login to the app` in one scenario. In another scenario I have `And I login to the app`.

I don't like all the `Then` `And` `Given` 's in step definitions. Is there a way to not have to specifically use these keywords and use some sort of wildcard? I've thought about just using `When` in step definitions. I just hate mixing all these keywords when they don't really matter anyway.

I wish I could define the step in my step_definition file without having to use various (meaningless) keywords in front of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to change this in your feature file, instead of using one of the step definition keywords (Given, When, Then, And, But) you can use an asterisk (*) in your feature file as a sort of bullet point.  Example

```
Scenario: Test Scenario
* run a sample step
* run a different sample step
```

This will generate

```
Given(/^run a sample step$/) do
  pending # express the regexp above with the code you wish you had
end

Given(/^run a different sample step$/) do
  pending # express the regexp above with the code you wish you had
end
```

Also, Gherkin supports adding languages, this uses a JSON file to define the keywords for the step.  This could be used to change what keywords were used for step definitions.

You could fork Gherkin and clone it.  Then edit i18n.json to add a new language which uses whatever keywords you wanted instead of these.  It currently supports pirate for example.  After this you would either have to submit a pull request for them to add the language definition to the project or build Gherkin yourself from the cloned fork (https://github.com/cucumber/gherkin/blob/master/README.md)

Here is the reference page for adding a language

https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Spoken-languages

Comment: I wish in my step definition I could just use something like `define (/I login to the app/)` ... I hate my step file having When's, Then's, And's, Given's ... blah blah. I wish I could define the step without having to use a keyword in front of it.

Comment: found a possible way to do update cucumber to support this capability.  See the edited answer for more details

Comment: If you want to add a generic define the change to i18n.jason would be the way to go.  You will probably have to run on a local build though as it doesn't really fit the way cucumber is supposed to work.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. I wish I could use a * in my step_definitions file. I like using `Given` `Then` `When` in the feature file. I just don't like mixing them all into a step_definition file. Just seems sloppy to me. idk.